# How to use Groovy variable into Extended Choice Jenkins Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, compilation, closures, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to use a Groovy variable as a value for Extended Choice plugin. Seems trivial, but doesn't work - fails with "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $COMPONENTS_LIST for class: groovy.lang.Binding".

Any ideas?

```
environment {
    COMPONENTS_LIST= "one two three"
}
parameters {
    extendedChoice (description: 'Components', multiSelectDelimiter: ' ', 
    name: 'Components_To_Deploy', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT', 
    value: $COMPONENTS_LIST, visibleItemCount: 3)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a syntax error, you are trying to set the named parameter `value` to the content of the variable `$COMPONENTS_LIST`; which doesn't exist. Also there's a problem with the scope of the variable; which needs to be available in both closures. So try defining a variable outside the scope of both closure with the value you need and then use the variables inside the closures, as in the following example:

```
def componentsList = "one two three"
environment {
    COMPONENTS_LIST = componentsList
}
parameters {
    extendedChoice (description: 'Components', multiSelectDelimiter: ' ', 
    name: 'Components_To_Deploy', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT', 
    value: componentsList, visibleItemCount: 3)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these methods fail with the same exception.

Comment: I just updated the answer with some extra consideration, my original answer wasn't considering the scope of the variable, only the syntax error in its usage.

Comment: Marco, thank you! Got it. Unfortunately,  the same thing seems to be undoable in Declarative Pipeline, but at least I understand the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a syntax issue. You have to use double quote to refer to you variable :

```
def COMPONENTS_LIST= "one two three"
parameters {
    extendedChoice (description: 'Components', multiSelectDelimiter: ' ', 
    name: 'Components_To_Deploy', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT', 
    value: "${COMPONENTS_LIST}", visibleItemCount: 3)
}
```

Comment: Instead of <value: "${COMPONENTS_LIST}"> you can simply use <value: COMPONENTS_LIST>: no quotes and no dollar-sign.